# luaotfload cannot load system font

Tags: fonts, luatex, texlive

(I have asked this question in `comp.text.tex` and `lualatex-dev@tug.org` mailling lists, but I still haven't got any reply. I know this website is not for bug report, but since no developer responded me, maybe my problem is only related to a specific type of setup, and possibly be helpful for someone who encounters the same error message).

I updated my texlive 2013 pretest on May 14, and luaotfload was updated
to v2.2 (2013/05/10). After the update, no matter I use fontspec or
luaotfload package in the preamble, lualatex cannot load system font.
Both produce the same error message. (The last update I made is May 17, and the problem still persist).

System info:
texlive 2013 pretest, last update on May 17. Archlinux x86_64.

Here's the error message:

```
! LuaTeX error .../texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.lua:85: a
ttempt to index global 'dir' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        .../texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.lua:85: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ...pt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/modutils.lua:57: in function 're
quire_module'
        [string "\directlua "]:1: in main chunk.
\lltxb@requirelua ...xluaescapestring {#2}" \fi )}

l.41 \fi
```

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not for bug reports. The pretest  version of TeX Live is, well, still in testing, so problems are expected. The [TeX Live mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live) is the place to go.

Comment: Things which are clear bug reports simply don't fit the format here. It often takes a while to get a reply on the mailing lists, but that is how it is. In particular, there are some big changes in the Lua side of things that are being worked through, and the people doing that work are aware there are issues.